# PHP for loop stop after value of 1

Tags: php

I have the following for loop that works great using variables and displaying relevant matches in an xml output.  I want to display only the first match (example _1.jpg) instead of looping thru and displaying the entire `$pic_count`.

I've tried to remove the `++` and also do change the math on the `<= $pic_count` to `!= >` etc.  How do I just show the `$pic_start` value of one and then exit the for loop?

```
for ($pic_start = 1; $pic_start <= $pic_count; $pic_start++) 
{
  echo '<photo isMain="1"><photoSmall><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoSmall><photoLarge><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoLarge></photo>';
}
```

Comment: `$pic_start = 1; echo ...` remove loop at all

Comment: If you only want to run it once, why bother with the loop at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put **[break;](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)** at the end of the loop. So your code will look like this,

```
for ($pic_start = 1; $pic_start <= $pic_count; $pic_start++) 
{
echo '<photo isMain="1"><photoSmall><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoSmall><photoLarge><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoLarge></photo>';
break; // will execute loop only once.
}
```

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.

We use **break** command to break the loop on certain condition, in your case we just need to break the loop after very first execution. So put that at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just use break in your loop :

```
$stop_value = 2; 
for ($pic_start = 1; $pic_start <= $pic_count; $pic_start++) 
{
     if ($pic_start == $stop_value) {
         break;
     } 
     echo '<photo isMain="1"><photoSmall><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoSmall><photoLarge><![CDATA[/feeds/' . $img . '/rets_images/' . $listing . '_' . $pic_start . '.jpg]]></photoLarge></photo>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for ($pic_start = 1; $pic_start <= $pic_count; $pic_start++) 
{
    echo ...;
    break;
}
```

This will break the for loop after the first iteration. 
But if this the case, why even use a for loop in the first place?